# Azure Databricks access got error code=403/Forbidden: 403-Unauthorized access to Org

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, firewall, workspace

I access to Azure Databricks workspace API
https://workspacexxx.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/list
and got error

"403/Forbidden: 403-Unauthorized access to Org:"

I try with postman and get result like this
{"error_code":"403","message":"Unauthorized access to Org: xxxx"}

It seems related to firewall/networks but I don't know exactly.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you giving authorization details while requesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is related to the IP Access List configured on your workspace. Make sure that traffic is going via VPN or correct HTTP proxy. You need to ask your Databricks administrator.

Comment: Thanks Alex, We solved it, It is a proxy problem